# JQuery Mobile select menu change event fires multiple times

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I have a [JQuery Mobile Multi-Page layout](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) and I want to trigger a function when a select menu on my site is changed.

Currently when the menu is changed three events fire.

I have put together [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/rzs8L/13/) that should show you what i'm facing.

1. From the main menu click *Web Settings*
2. Change the *Theme* option on the page
   *Notice the three alerts*

Here is my code to register the event

```
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function() {
    $("#settings-theme").bind("change", function(event) {
        alert(event.target);
    });
});
```

Things I have tried:

- Changing the `data-native-menu="false"` to `true` removed one of the event firings.
- Removed all other *pages* except ***web settings*** and that also reduced the number of events firing to two.
- In JSFiddle, Framework Options > Head (nowrap) changed to DomReady also removed a event fire.

---

***Update***
It appears that `pagecreate` is fired every time a page is 'first-viewed' as well as twice when the homepage is loaded. 
So by the time the settings page is loaded the event has been binded three times.. still no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).bind("ready", function() {
    $("#settings-theme").live("change", function() {
        alert("changed");
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).bind("ready", function() {
    $("#pg-settings").delegate("#settings-theme", "change", function() {
        alert("changed");
    });
});
```